# Oracle Cursor for dropping users

Tags: plsql, cursor

I have a list of users that I need to drop from a schema.  I created the table OWNERS_TO_REMOVE that has the names of the users that need to be dropped.  I tried created the following cursor to drop the users, but it didn't work.  Does it need a minor adjustment or do I need to drop the users in a completely different way?

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_remove_owners IS
        SELECT OWNER FROM OWNERS_TO_REMOVE;

    v_owner OWNERS_TO_REMOVE.OWNER%TYPE;

BEGIN
    OPEN c_remove_owners;

    LOOP
        FETCH c_remove_owners INTO v_owner;

        EXIT WHEN c_remove_owners%NOTFOUND;

        DROP USER v_owner CASCADE;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c_remove_owners;
END;
```

/

Comment: do you get an error, when you execute it ?

Comment: ORA-06550: line 10, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DROP" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null
   pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

Comment: There is no `drop` keyword in PL/SQL - you'll need [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm). You might also look at [Cursor FOR loops](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm).

Comment: Thanks William, I will check out those options.